# Spring Boot - Null pointer on custom Query

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I was doing a custom query to check if the given data exist in the mongodb database. Below are my codes that I have done.

```
 package com.royangular.royAngularProject.repositories;


import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.royangular.royAngularProject.models.ContactUs;



@Repository
public interface ContactUsRepository extends MongoRepository<ContactUs, String> {

    @Query("{'name' : ?0}")//, contactEmail : ?0, phoneNumber : ?0}")
    public List<ContactUs> findBynameAndcontactEmailAndphoneNumber(String name);//, String contactEmail, String phoneNumber);

}
```

The classthat call the repo:

```
package com.royangular.royAngularProject.controllersContact;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

import com.royangular.royAngularProject.models.ContactUs;
import com.royangular.royAngularProject.repositories.ContactUsRepository;

public class QueryDBCheck {

     @Autowired
     ContactUsRepository contactUsRepository;

     @Autowired
     MongoTemplate mongoTemplate ;

    public boolean queryDB (ContactUs contactus)
    {
        List<ContactUs> colleagues = new ArrayList<ContactUs>(); 

        if (contactUsRepository.findBynameAndcontactEmailAndphoneNumber(contactus.getName())==null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            colleagues = contactUsRepository.findBynameAndcontactEmailAndphoneNumber("dasdsad");//, contactus.getContactEmail(), contactus.getPhoneNumber());

        }


        if (colleagues.size()==0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }
}
```

I got a null pointer at `contactUsRepository.findBynameAndcontactEmailAndphoneNumber(contactus.getName())`.May I know what is the issue and how I do need to do to resolve it. It prevent the code from continuing. Sorry I was new to mongodb with spring boot. Could you also include why is being done and how is being done as so that everyone in the community can learned.

Comment: Are you sure `contacts.getName()` returns a `non-null` value?

Comment: @ETO Yes I am sure it is not null, I even printed on the logs before which stated is not null.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the `Query` annotation from your method. You don't need it in this particular case.
2. Respect *camelCase* notation while naming your `JPA` query. (Note that the first letters of parameter names in method name should be capitalized).

   ```
   @Repository
   public interface ContactUsRepository extends MongoRepository<ContactUs, String> {

       public List<ContactUs> findByNameAndContactEmailAndPhoneNumber(String name, String contactEmail, String phoneNumber);

   }
   ```